# Hitting ArrowTypeError: Input object was not a NumPy array when trying to upload a geodataframe to BigQuery in a Python notebook

Tags: python, google-bigquery, geopandas, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I'm using a function in a Python notebook to try to upload a geodataframe into a BigQuery Table:

```
def geopandas_to_gbq(geodataframe, dataset_name, table_name, replace_table=True):
    """
    This function loads a GeoPandas GeoDataFrame into a BigQuery table. The
    geometry field on the data frame will be configured correctly within BQ.
    Note that there is a function called to_gbq that exists on Pandas already.
    But that function won't create geography fields in the appropriate places.
    Instead it will upload geographic data as a string.
    """
    import warnings; warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', message='.*initial implementation of Parquet.*')

    geog_field_name = geodataframe._geometry_column_name
    print(f'Loading data into `{dataset_name}.{table_name}` with geography field `{geog_field_name}`...')
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        schema=[
            bigquery.SchemaField(geog_field_name, bigquery.enums.SqlTypeNames.GEOGRAPHY)
        ],
        write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE" if replace_table else "WRITE_APPEND",
    )
    client = bigquery.Client()
    job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
        geodataframe.to_crs(4326), f'{dataset_name}.{table_name}', job_config=job_config
    )
    return job.result()
```

I'm creating the geodataframe like this :

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import wkt

df = pd.read_csv('/content/mycsvfile.csv')
df['geometry'] = df.geowkt.apply(wkt.loads)
df.drop('geowkt', axis=1, inplace=True) #Drop WKT column

# Geopandas GeoDataFrame
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geometry',crs='epsg:4326')
gdf.head()
```

`geopandas_to_gbq(gdf, 'TEST', 'upload_table', replace_table=True)`

It seems to work fine but when I run the function I hit what seems to be an arrow error.

```
7 frames
<ipython-input-8-02fd56f750de> in geopandas_to_gbq(geodataframe, dataset_name, table_name, replace_table)
     98     client = bigquery.Client()
     99     job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
--> 100         geodataframe.to_crs(4326), f'{dataset_name}.{table_name}', job_config=job_config
    101     )
    102     return job.result()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py in load_table_from_dataframe(self, dataframe, destination, num_retries, job_id, job_id_prefix, location, project, job_config, parquet_compression)
   1608                     job_config.schema,
   1609                     tmppath,
-> 1610                     parquet_compression=parquet_compression,
   1611                 )
   1612             else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/_pandas_helpers.py in dataframe_to_parquet(dataframe, bq_schema, filepath, parquet_compression)
    366         raise ValueError("pyarrow is required for BigQuery schema conversion.")
    367 
--> 368     arrow_table = dataframe_to_arrow(dataframe, bq_schema)
    369     pyarrow.parquet.write_table(arrow_table, filepath, compression=parquet_compression)
    370 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/_pandas_helpers.py in dataframe_to_arrow(dataframe, bq_schema)
    333         arrow_names.append(bq_field.name)
    334         arrow_arrays.append(
--> 335             bq_to_arrow_array(get_column_or_index(dataframe, bq_field.name), bq_field)
    336         )
    337 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/_pandas_helpers.py in bq_to_arrow_array(series, bq_field)
    185     if bq_field.field_type.upper() in schema._STRUCT_TYPES:
    186         return pyarrow.StructArray.from_pandas(series, type=arrow_type)
--> 187     return pyarrow.array(series, type=arrow_type)
    188 
    189 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyarrow/array.pxi in pyarrow.lib.array()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyarrow/array.pxi in pyarrow.lib._ndarray_to_array()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyarrow/error.pxi in pyarrow.lib.check_status()

ArrowTypeError: Input object was not a NumPy array
```

I can upload a `df` fine with the geometry as a string and then just create a copy of the table and convert the string to a geography. But I'd like to figure out what's wrong with this upload function as is.

Comment: Hi OP, is your Notebook hosted in GCP? In addition, can you please provide sample data for proper replication of your use case?

Comment: Hi OP, I tested your use case using the sample data I got in here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/geospatial-data#loading_wkt_or_wkb_data and using a notebook that is hosted in GCP, and successfully loaded the geodataframe to BigQuery. Will just wait for your sample data for exact and better replication of your use case,

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and the solution that worked for me was to specifically define the geometry as '**GEOGRAPHY**'. This was my GeoDataFrame:
[image]

At first, I uploaded it to BigQuery with this:

```
pandas_gbq.to_gbq(df, destination_table='dataset.polygons_test2', project_id="my_project")
```

And I got the error. After searching for solutions I've added `table_schema`:

```
pandas_gbq.to_gbq(df, destination_table='dataset.polygons_test2',table_schema=[{'name':'geometry','type':"GEOGRAPHY"}],project_id="my_project")
```